Knowing when to stop benchmarking
I have a basic question that I'm sure must have been asked before, but I don't know the words to Google...
I do a lot of benchmarking software, ie comparing two different implementations of the same function. I'm dealing with indeterminacy because modern computers run a lot of stuff in the background, so my normal solution to this is to run tests (eg) 100 times, and look at the median and results.
But if I'm doing a test and the first (eg) 5 runs show a significant difference (like a 10x improvement), I can probably stop the test there and declare a winner.
I figure that knowing when to stop the test should be a function of the number of runs and the delta between the two medians so far.
My questions are:

Does this principle have a name?
How do I determine the function that tells me I can stop the test?
What number of runs is reasonable in order to be confident in the result?
Is there some formula for figuring this out?
Is there any benchmarking software that operates like this? (I use Linux btw, but would be interested in anything)


This is not at all how hypothesis testing is supposed to be used, you are abusing something which has specific use cases and that will, in it's current form, lead to many false conclusions. Also, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

@user2974951 What? There's no higher-order problem here, I benchmark stuff and I want to know how I should be testing it. Are you saying I should be asking about how to write optimal software instead? If you have insights on that please share.

But there is, this can be very context dependent. What are you benchmarking, how, why? Give us more context on the underlying problem.

@user2974951 Benchmarking is something I do pretty often, and it's all sorts of things. I operate in garbage-collected dynamic languages (Ruby and Nodejs) on operating systems that may be doing all sorts of unrelated things at any given point in time, so I don't know how else I can measure the performance of a given piece of software.

I think useful keywords to google are "optional stopping" and "sequential analysis". This links may be helpful: https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/02-errorcontrol.html#sec-optionalstopping and https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/10-sequential.html. (Personally I'm happy for this question to stay open, it's not very detailed but the general aim seems clear and on-topic)

I don't see any reason why this question needs to be closed. The way this website treats newcomers, especially people with less background in statistics who otherwise ask valid questions (but maybe not with the right terminology) is the opposite of helpful
